# If statetement inside class

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, switch-statement

I'm trying to create a map of hospitals using Google Maps API. Radius of circle is number of beds in that hospital. Also, I would like to have different colors for different types of hospitals. That could be done with IF or SWITCH statement, but neither worked. Here I am attaching example with IF statement.

Problem is with the statement `if (citymap[city].tip = 1)` (commented out below).

I'm sure that the problem is wrong use of function in this place.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Circles</title>
    <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map {
        height: 100%;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <script>

var citymap = {
  KBC_ZAGREB: {
    center: {lat: 45.823554, lng: 16.005904},
    beds: 1975,
    contentString: "KBC ZAGREB, 1975 kreveta",
    tip: 1
  },
  KBC_SPLIT: {
    center: {lat: 43.503908, lng: 16.457924},
    beds: 1521,
    contentString: "KBC SPLIT, 1521 kreveta",
    tip: 1
  },
  KBC_RIJEKA: {
    center: {lat: 45.332623, lng: 14.425665},
    beds: 1191,
    contentString: "KBC RIJEKA, 1192 kreveta",
    tip: 1
  },
  KBC_OSIJEK: {
    center: {lat: 45.558230, lng: 18.711740},
    beds: 1160,
    contentString: "KBC OSIJEK, 1160 kreveta",
    tip: 1
  },
   KBC_SESTRE_MILOSRDNICE: {
    center: {lat: 45.815438, lng: 15.953599},
    beds: 1207,
    contentString: "KBC SESTRE MILOSRDNICE, 1207 kreveta",
    tip: 1
  },
  KB_DUBRAVA: {
    center: {lat: 45.834369, lng: 16.035823},
    beds: 625,
    contentString: "KB DUBRAVA, 625 kreveta",
    tip: 2
  },
  KB_MERKUR: {
    center: {lat: 45.820832, lng: 15.997447},
    beds: 345,
    contentString: "KB MERKUR, 345 kreveta",
    tip: 2
  },
  KB_SVETI_DUH: {
    center: {lat: 45.820140, lng: 15.938853},
    beds: 554,
    contentString: "KB SVETI DUH, 554 kreveta",
    tip: 2
  }

};

function initMap() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat: 45.811076, lng: 15.979270},
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  for (var city in citymap) {

    var cityCircle = new google.maps.Circle({

        strokeColor: '#FF0000',
        fillColor: '#FF0000',

//    if (citymap[city].tip = 1){
//      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
//      fillColor: '#FF0000'
//      } else if (citymap[city].tip = 2){
//      strokeColor: '#3333cc',
//      fillColor: '#3333cc'
//      },

      strokeOpacity: 0.8,
      strokeWeight: 2,
      fillOpacity: 0.35,
      map: map,
      position: citymap[city].center,
      center: citymap[city].center,
      radius: Math.sqrt(citymap[city].beds) * 10
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: citymap[city].contentString
    });

    cityCircle.addListener('click', function() {
        infowindow.open(map, cityCircle);
    });

  }
}

    </script>
    <script async defer
        src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?signed_in=true&callback=initMap"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `citymap[city].tip = 1` set the value `1` to `citymap[city].tip`, use `==` or `===` for comparison

Answer (score 2):

Single equal `=` used to assign value, If you want to compare you could use double equals `==` to compare two values or triple equals `===` to check also the type of those compared values, in your case you can use double or triple signs :

```
if(citymap[city].tip == '1')
//OR
if(citymap[city].tip === '1'))
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Try to show variable in console using `console.log(citymap[city].tip)` to make sure that it return something.

Comment: Yes, it returns 1 or 2, depending on value of `citymap[city].tip`

Comment: Ok try to compar it as string by adding quotes to `1`, check my update.

Comment: :) try `console.log(citymap[city].tip == 1, citymap[city].tip == '1')`, and check what it will return.

Comment: in meantime, I made a change in code. I freated separated function `function createCircle(map, position,center,radius, data, tip)` and added this conditions there. Now it works. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
if (citymap[city].tip == 1)
```

to check.